# add ImageView to ViewFlipper not working

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, viewflipper

I want add ImageView on ViewFlipper and try this code

```
ViewFlipper flipVertical = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.slideVer);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("sdcard/vm/picture/vertical/VB-Logo.png");
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
flipVertical.addView(imageView);
```

nothing effect with that code, same as when I use

```
ViewFlipper flipVertical = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.slideVer);
Uri uriImage = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/vm/picture/vertical/VB-Logo.png");
imageView.setImageURI(uriImage);
flipVertical.addView(imageView);
```

What should I do?? :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below...

```
     ViewFlipper flipVertical = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.slideVer);
     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/vm/picture/vertical/VB-Logo.png");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    flipVertical.addView(imageView, params);
```

If you didn't add the permission to access SDCard then add these permission in the `Manifest.xml` file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Is set in AndroidManifest.xml 
I just try your code but nothing happen :( 
Thank's for the answer.